# Identity involving derivatives inside a scalar product

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been tying to figure out why these two equalities hold true given a $C^2$-function $\Phi$,
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, the author must have stated somewhere the assumption that $\|\partial\Phi/\partial t\big|_{r=0}\| = 1$. The second equality follows immediately from the product rule for the inner product:
$$\frac d{dt}\langle A(t),B(t)\rangle = \langle \frac{dA}{dt},B(t)\rangle + \langle A(t),\frac{dB}{dt}\rangle.$$